# No response while and after rendering

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

When i render in Blender everything works fine, until I put the window into the background. Sometimes, when I go then tab back into Blender, it says "not responding". Interestingly, it still renders fine, as I can see in the file size of the output.

The actually problematic part is that, after finishing the render, it still gives no response, leaving me no choice but to terminate it, loosing all unsaved progress. I know I can always save before rendering, but sometimes I forget that...

Comment: Try to run Blender from a command line to see if it outputs something on it.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling, clearing settings and preferences, then reinstalling it?

Comment: well, the thing is, that it does not happen always and I currently have no idea when it does, which makes it hard to identify the problem since I don't want to keep the console open constantly...